# Trouble using browserify and module export in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browserify

I have some problems using browserify for the first time. I have an HTML page using the Google Map API. When the map is loaded, I want to call an "initMap" function, like this:

```
  <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApiKey&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing&v=weekly" async>
</script>
```

initMap is defined in a Map.js file. So far everything works fine. But now I want to use the [wicket](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket) module in my Map.js file. So I use Browserify to require my module in my js file, since I am not familiar with RequireJS and other module loaders. I only know the NodeJS syntax.

So I use Browserify like this : `browserify Map.js -o bundle.js`

Then I add this to my HTML.

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

But when I load the page, I get an error : `Uncaught (in promise)  Object { message: "initMap is not a function"`

I guess I need to export some things but I don't know how to do it, I'm new to javascript. I also saw that there is a -standalone option in Browerify but I'm not sure how to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure about the path of where the bundled module is stored.

And if you just want to add a hosted module (script tag), you can use https://wzrd.in (cheap-lazy way)

Comment: The bundle is in the same folder as my HTML.
Thankl you for the link, but I don"t really know how to use it